# Como cargar datos en Spinner Determinar manera en que se muestran

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema con la vista de los spinner en Android, la lista de datos que cargo en el spinner esta ordenada correctamente de la A-Z pero al seleccionar el spinner se muestra a partir de la Z y tengo que recorrer el scroll view hacia arriba.

¿Podrían ayudarme para que se muestre desde la A hacia abajo?

Asi es como tengo mi código:

```
        adtInsuredProfession = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) {


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Log.e("VALORES SPINNER ", String.valueOf(position) + " " + convertView );

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (position == getCount()) {

                ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(getItem(getCount())); //"Hint to be displayed"
            }

            return v;
        }
```

Comment: Eso depende de como estan ordenados tus datos, podrías agregar el array con el que llenas tu Spinner? y el código correcto con el que llenas el spinner!

Answer (score 5):

Lo que comentas depende de como están ordenados tus datos o de como los introduces.

Noto que dentro de `getView()` tratas de mostrar los valores al `Spinner` lo cual es incorrecto. Tal vez existe una pequeña confusión, agrego un ejemplo de como llenar un `Spinner` con valores de un `ArrayList`:

```
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>
                                           arg0,View arg1,int arg2,long arg3){
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
    // Elementos en Spinner
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    values.add("A");
    values.add("B");
    values.add("C");
    values.add("...");
    values.add("X");
    values.add("Y");
    values.add("Z");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Como puedes notar los valores son agregados dentro de un ArrayList y en el orden en el que son introducidos así deben ser mostrados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys, estoy trabajando el la solución es que es un código que ya estaba hecho y yo estoy apenas  comprendiendo la lógica de lo que se hizo pero tus comentarios me fueron de gran utilidad.

Comment: Que bien Dulce! Saludos!